# Howto do a LEFT JOIN in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

Hello there (or as we say Moin Moin)!

I am new to django development (version 2.0) and do not understand how to do a LEFT JOIN in django-syntax.

For example I have the following models:

```
class Units(models.Model):
    UnitID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    
 class MappingOperatorUnits(models.Model):
    OperatorID = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    UnitID = models.ForeignKey('Units', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
class Participants(models.Model):
    UnitID = models.ForeignKey('Units', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    LessonID = models.ForeignKey('Lessons', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    OperatorID = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    NumberParticipants = models.SmallIntegerField()
```

Now I am trying to do a query like

```
SELECT * 
FROM MappingOperatorUnits
LEFT JOIN Units
ON ON MappingOperatorUnits.UnitID = Units.UnitID
LEFT JOIN Participants
ON MappingOperatorUnits.UnitID = Participants.UnitID
```

and what I want to be the result is something like this:

```
+-------------------+-----------------------+---------------------------------+
| Units.Description | Participants.LessonID | Participants.NumberParticipants |
+-------------------+-----------------------+---------------------------------+
| TeamA             | 1                     | 0                               |
+-------------------+-----------------------+---------------------------------+
| TeamB             | 1                     | 3                               |
+-------------------+-----------------------+---------------------------------+
| TeamC             | NULL                  | NULL                            |
+-------------------+-----------------------+---------------------------------+
| TeamA             | 2                     | 2                               |
+-------------------+-----------------------+---------------------------------+
| TeamB             | 2                     | 5                               |
+-------------------+-----------------------+---------------------------------+
| TeamC             | 2                     | 1                               |
+-------------------+-----------------------+---------------------------------+
```

I tried a lot of things in manage.py's shell but din't come to the solution. Anybody can help me to get it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can annotate use [**`.values(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/) to load values of a referenced model:

```
MappingOperatorUnits.objects.values(
    'UnitID__Description',
    'UnitID__participants__LessonID',
    'UnitID__participants__NumberParticipants'
)
```

This produces a query that looks like:

```
SELECT units.Description,
       participants.LessonID_id
       participants.NumberParticipants
FROM mappingoperatorunits
INNER JOIN units ON mappingoperatorunits.UnitID_id = units.UnitID
LEFT OUTER JOIN participants ON units.UnitID = participants.UnitID_id
```

The `INNER JOIN` is an optimization that can be done here, since it is a non-NULLable `ForeignKey`, and thus we know there is always a related `Units` record.

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Unit` instead of <s>`Units`</s>.

---

> **Note**: Normally one does not add a suffix `_id` to a `ForeignKey` field, since Django
> will automatically add a "twin" field with an `_id` suffix. Therefore it should
> be `unit`, instead of <s>`UnitID`</s>.

Comment: This works perfectly for me! Thank you.
Is it possible to rename the a bit long fieldnames in the resulting queryset?

Comment: @CptCotton: you you import `from django.db.models import F` and then you can write `.values(short_name=F('long_name'))`

Comment: I just figuered out that this solution would not fit one important case. If I have an mapping Operator/Unit in MappingOperatorUnits but no participants for this unit in Participants I wont get an row in my result. This case is row 3 in my example result table.

Comment: @CptConnon: normally that is not a problem, since we use a `LEFT OUTER` join.